# Angular 8 main-es2015 does not load the entire code over HTTP protocol

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm having a problem with main-es2015 javascript file generated by ng build --prod on Angular 8.

When I try to open the website over HTTPS protocol, it works because the browser reads all the main-es2015 file and the file ends like that:

```
throw t.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",t})}e.keys=function(){return[]},e.resolve=e,n.exports=e,e.id="zn8P"}},[[0,0]]]); // the end
```

This is how the scrollbar looks like over HTTPS:

[image: scrollprint]

But if you try to open over HTTP protocol (without SSL), the file ends at this line:

```
else i.useClass=n;e=j().compileInjectable(q,`ng: // ... where's the rest of the code?
```

This is how the scrollbar looks like over HTTP:

[image: scrollprint2]

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Somehow, the server was trying to access a file that doesn't exists, that the name is something like ".pagespeed.js". I searched for it and found this...

You need to add this to your .htaccess:

```
Modpagespeed Off
```